Setting Rotate Label tool pivot/anchor point in QGIS 3.x
In older versions of QGIS 2.x, I recall the pivot/anchor point for interactive label rotation was the origin point of the selected parent symbol, seen as the red dot inside the middle of the 28 label in the screen shot provided. The label extents box (green) would rotate around this origin point, allowing you visually align the edges of a text label to a nearby boundary.
When using the Rotate Label tool in the current versions of QGIS 3.x, a red arrow appears outside the target label, after selecting it. This red arrow is now the pivot point for the target label and sits outside the label, away from its true origin (the red dot). When performing the rotation, an empty blue label extent box rotates around the red arrow, moving away from the green label extent box, away from the target label, until finalising the rotation with a left click. The target label remains in place, rotated using the angle in reference to the final position of the blue extent box.
I would like the red arrow pivot point to use the true origin of the selected text (red dot). Is there a setting, or method, that controls or sets where this arrow appears when performing an interactive label rotation using the Rotate Label tool?


